# Can I un-cache one image? Or should I do things differently?

Tags: php, caching

I allow users to add a profile picture of themselves to an account, pretty standard stuff.

To make things simple, when they update their image I simply overwrite the image they currently have stored (its not a big part of what we do so simple approach)

So, page is shown with their current image, they can then choose to upload a new one, the uploaded file is then saved, image URL updated in MySQL table and page is displayed again.

The image is uploaded correctly, MySQL table updated correctly, but the image is cached so old image shows on page even though they have uploaded a new one.

Can I un cache one image? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For avoiding image caching you can simply add a query sting in the image src. Best would be adding a date time.

```
    {$t = getDate();}
     and in your image src add: src= "path.jpg?t=".$t
```

For this you need not to change anything for new image..Date time automatically gets changed every second ;)
Hope it helps..

Comment: That would creat an image URL that is never cached including when it hasn't been updated. Change the date part to the dye the image was uploaded and it would work though.

Comment: @JasonSperske hmmm..correct..But this overhead can be beard seeing the usefulness it has when image is changed..

Answer (score 1):

Use versioning. In the link for the image, instead of `abc.jpg` say `abc.jpg?v=5`. And when a new image is uploaded, change the number.

[see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399387/force-browser-to-re-read-cached-images)